# How to access Android hardware by pressing volume key

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-fragments

I am making an application and I want to make app in such a way that user directly open that by using volume key, suppose user click twice the volume+ or volume- buttom and the app will directly open without home screen or without any interuption.

I want to add this functionality using the code in Android Studio. If anyone know how to add this, please help...

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not **App/Code** nor **Android Studio** related but device related, If the Original Equipment Manufacturer will allow a device to have a shortcut button it could be possible to achieve that on those devices.

Cheers.